# Django function based views vs class based views which one we should use in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm just started learning Django v2.2. I'm little bit confused about function based views and class based views which one I should learn first which help me in my future.

Answer (score 3):

Some views are best implemented as CBVs, and others are best implemented as FBVs.

If you aren’t sure which method to choose, see the following chart:

[image]